# How can I set a small margin difference on merging amount in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to dataframes which contains ID, Name, Amount and Stock details. 
Actual df details are as follows:

```
df1.shape - (1873, 3)
df2.shape - (1443, 4)

df1.columns - Index(['ID', 'Name', 'Amount'])
df2.columns - Index(['Name', 'gross total', 'Avail', 'date'])
```

I need to merge these two dataframes on the basis of Amount (As there is no ID in Df2 and there are some Names missing on Df2). But difference user have entered the Amount and gross total as rounded off. So how can I merge the values with a tolerance limit of $2 in Amount and gross total.

Actual data extracts:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['100/2018-19', '67/2018-19', 'GAC/0054'], 'Name':['GUARD INDUSTRIES','GUARD INDUSTRIES','G-CHIEF APPLIANCES'],'Amount':[51428,1180400,24639]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['G-CHIEF APPLIANCES', 'ANIS INTERNATIONAL', '', 'GUARD INDUSTRIES'], 'Avail':['S30','AK12', '46', '47'],'gross total':[24640,383675,51430,74360], 'Date':['22/02/2018', '22/02/2018', '22/02/2018', '23/02/2018'] })

Out:
            ID                Name   Amount
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639

                 Name Avail  gross total        Date
0  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES   S30        24640  22/02/2018
1  ANIS INTERNATIONAL  AK12       383675  22/02/2018
2                 NaN    46        51430  22/02/2018
3    GUARD INDUSTRIES    47        74360  23/02/2018
```

As I do merge, I don't get any match:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True, left_on='Amount', right_on='gross total')

Out:
            ID                Name     Amount Avail  gross total        Date      _merge
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
3          NaN  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES        NaN   S30      24640.0  22/02/2018  right_only
4          NaN  ANIS INTERNATIONAL        NaN  AK12     383675.0  22/02/2018  right_only
5          NaN                 NaN        NaN    46      51430.0  22/02/2018  right_only
6          NaN    GUARD INDUSTRIES        NaN    47      74360.0  23/02/2018  right_only
```

*desired result* (As there are two rows with just $2 difference I want them to be a match).

```
            ID                Name     Amount Avail  gross total        Date      _merge
0  100/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES    51428.0    46      51428.0  22/02/2018        both
1   67/2018-19    GUARD INDUSTRIES  1180400.0   NaN          NaN         NaN   left_only
2     GAC/0054  G-CHIEF APPLIANCES    24639.0   S30      24639.0  22/02/2018        both
3          NaN  ANIS INTERNATIONAL        NaN  AK12     383675.0  22/02/2018  right_only
4          NaN    GUARD INDUSTRIES        NaN    47      74360.0  23/02/2018  right_only
```

In the desired result I gave gross total value as 24639 and 51428. I dont mind if it is 24640 and 51430 as in df2, I just want them to match.

when I try:

```
df1['in_margin'] = df1['Amount'].between(df2['gross total']-2, df2['gross total']+2)
df2['in_margin'] = df1['in_margin'].replace(False, -999)
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Name','in_margin'], how='outer', indicator=True)
```

On that same line itself I get a value error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/../test margin.py", line 12, in <module>
    df1['in_margin'] = df1['Amount'].between(df2['gross total']-2, df2['gross total']+2)
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4364, in between
    lmask = self >= left
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "E:\..\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 521, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects```
````

Comment: have a look at `merge_asof`.

Comment: Actually I haven't. But there is no ```how=outer, indicator=True```, so how can I get the balance entries which aren't matched? Usually I do it by ```merge(how=outer, indicator=True)``` then taking the ```left_only and right_only``` to another df. Please help

Comment: @QuangHoang please tell me how can I get unmatched entries